# How to use the Ascending order sort in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm new to Power Shell.  I have a backup log text file that outputs to my C drive as a text file in Power Shell. The problem I'm facing is that older logs are displayed on top while newer logs are at the bottom.

I have a daily backup of 5 servers, if I want to check the latest backup with respect to date and time for the log, I have to scroll down to see the most recent text. I need a Power Shell script that can display the most recent backup with New on top and Old at the bottom.

```
$MesssagyBody = $MesssagyBody + ($ZIPSession | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={($_.name).Substring(0, $_.name.LastIndexOf("("))}} ,@{n="Start Time";e={$_.CreationTime}},@{n="End Time";e={$_.EndTime}},Result,@{n="Details";e={($TaskSessions | sort creationtime -Descending | select -first 1).Title}})
  }

  }
```

here is the out put

```
Name       : A_2019-06-28T161029 
Start Time : 6/28/2019 4:10:29 PM
End Time   : 6/28/2019 5:09:33 PM
Result     : Warning
Details    : Using source proxy cranach.cs.caw.edu (onhost)


Name       : B_2019-06-28T170027 
Start Time : 6/28/2019 5:00:27 PM
End Time   : 6/28/2019 7:00:23 PM
Result     : Warning
Details    : Using source proxy cranach.cs.caw.edu (onhost)


Name       : C_2019-06-28T160540 
Start Time : 6/28/2019 4:05:40 PM
End Time   : 6/28/2019 7:04:10 PM
Result     : Warning
Details    : Using source proxy cranach.cs.caw.edu (onhost)
```

Comment: if all you want is to see the newest lines add to the file, take a look at `Get-Help Get-Content -Parameter Tail`. [*grin*]

Comment: thank you so much Lee, with this script, does it sort in ascending order all daily backups? for instance if a backup is scheduled to run at 5 pm, it should be the newest log in c drive after completion  while older beneath it.

Comment: so you want `| Sort LastWriteTime -Ascending` then maybe add ` | Select -Last 5` ? Or possibly simpler `| Select -First 5` to just see the 5 newest files.

Comment: Are you saying here you want the latest backup of each server, or do you simply want to all in descending order of the Last Write Time? If the former, how do you tell which file is for what server?

Comment: @liliyons - normally, info added to a log file is added at the _end of the file_. so, if your logs are in the usual "newest last" order, then you should get the newest few lines with `-Tail`. then you can sort the lines by whatever datetime info each contains. ///// if you want something more specific than that, you will need to post some sample data ... add it to your Question [with code formatting], not as a comment.

Comment: Use what @LeeDailey commented. To 'sort' you can also use `[Array]::Reverse()` on the resulting lines.

Comment: Appreciate everyone for your prompt contributions. here is the scripts